# how to draw for range loop in a flowchart

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, range, flowchart

I tried:

```
while True:
    n = int(input("enter: "))

    if n > 1:

       for i in range(2,n):
           if (n % i) == 0:
               print(n,"is not a prime number")
               break
       else:
           print(n,"is a prime number")

    else:
       print(n,"is not a prime number")
```

how to draw for range loop in a flowchart?

Comment: the line before the code formatting is wrong sorry

Comment: You can edit your post, eh. Speaking of, can you explain what exactly the issue is?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile i dont know how to draw/write the "for i in range(2,n):" in a flow chart

Comment: Yes, I read the post. I was trying to get more details. Do you know how to draw flowcharts in general? Do you know how to draw loops?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile yes i do

Answer (score 1):

It should be somewhat like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
def password():
    '''buat password baru'''
    try:
        pw1 = input('Input Your old Password !\n ')
        if pw1 in pw:
            pw[pw.index(pw1)] = input('Input your new password !\n')
        elif pw1 not in pw: 
            print('Your password is not same, please try again !')
            password()
    except ValueError:
        print('Error, Please input your password again !')
        password()
    print('you add new password is successed ')
    menu_utama2()
 
def notifikasi():
    '''Riwayat Transaksi'''
    print('='*57)
    print('|'+'{:^55}'.format('Riwayat Transaksi')+'|')
    print('='*57)
    n = 1
    r = z = 0
    if len(keuntungan) > 0 and len(kerugian)>0:
        for k in range(len(keuntungan)+len(kerugian)):
            notif_awal(k)
            while True:
                if k % 2==0 and len(keuntungan) > z: 
                    j = int(k/2)
                    print('|  '+'Pilihan Anda\t\t:'+'Benar'.center(31)+'|')
                    print('|  '+'Mendapatkan Keuntungan:'+'Rp {:0,}'.format(keuntungan[j]).center(31)+'|')    
                    z+=1
                    break
                elif k % 2 == 1 and len(kerugian) > r:
                    j = int(k-n)
                    print('|  '+'Pilihan Anda\t\t:'+'salah'.center(31)+'|')
                    print('|  '+'Mendapatkan Kerugian\t:'+'Rp {:0,}'.format(kerugian[j]).center(31)+'|')
                    n+=1
                    r+=1
                    break
                else:
                    k+=1
                    continue
            print('='*57,flush = True)
            
    elif len(keuntungan) > 0 or len(kerugian) > 0:
        for k in range(len(keuntungan)+len(kerugian)):
            notif_awal(k)
            if len(keuntungan) > 0:
                print('|  '+'Pilihan Anda\t\t:'+'Benar'.center(31)+'|')
                print('|  '+'Mendapatkan Keuntungan:'+'Rp {:0,}'.format(keuntungan[k]).center(31)+'|')
                
            else:
                print('|  '+'Pilihan Anda\t\t:'+'Salah'.center(31)+'|')
                print('|  '+'Mendapatkan Kerugian\t:'+'Rp {:0,}'.format(kerugian[k]).center(31)+'|')
            print('='*57,flush = True)
            
    else:
        print('Anda Tidak memiliki Kerugian maupun keuntungan, Silahkan Trading Terlebih Dahulu',flush = True)
    menu_utama2()
```

To Flowchart